# Including variable inside an embedding gravity forms

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to add a variable inside an array of an embedding gravity forms to populate 2 hidden fields: email and jobname.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

    $email = get_field( "email_application" );
    $jobtitle = get_the_title();

    gravity_form( 5, false, false, false, array('email'=>'echo "$email";','jobname'=>'print "$jobtitle";'), false); 
?>
```

I know that echo, print or just the variable doesn't work as it show like this in my code:

```
<input name="input_6" id="input_5_6" type="hidden" value="print $jobtitle" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false">
```

and

```
<input name="input_5" id="input_5_5" type="hidden" value="echo "$email";" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false">
```

**Instead I should get:**

```
<input name="input_6" id="input_5_6" type="hidden" value="My job title" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false">
```

and

```
<input name="input_5" id="input_5_5" type="hidden" value="myaddress@email.com" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false">
```

I don't know a lot of PHP so if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using php in the code you showed you can just use variable names as shown in the code below:

```
gravity_form( 5, false, false, false, array('email'=>$email,'jobname'=>$jobtitle), false);
```